# 7 - Update a user with services

Tags: 7, users, services

I'm using Drupal 7 and the services module and I'm trying to update a user profile using PHP & Curl.
Do I always have to login before sending  a "PUT/update" ?

This is my code so far :

```
<?php


// REST Server URL
$request_url = 'http://mywebsite/end/user/login';

// User data
$user_data = array(
  'username' => 'user2',
  'password' => 'pass1',
);

// cURL
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // Do a regular HTTP POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($user_data)); // Set POST data
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

print $response;

$http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
// Check if login was successful
if ($http_code == 200) {
  // Convert json response as array
  $logged_user = json_decode($response);
}
else {
  // Get error msg
  $http_message = curl_error($curl);
  die($http_message);
}

print_r($logged_user);

// REST Server URL
$request_url = 'http://mywebsite.com/end/user/8&XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug';

$user_data = array('current_pass' => 'pass1', 'pass' => 'pass2');

// Define cookie session
$cookie_session = $logged_user->session_name . '=' . $logged_user->sessid;

// cURL
$curl = curl_init($request_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json',
    'Content-type: application/json')); // Accept JSON response
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); // FALSE);  // Ask to not return Header
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "$cookie_session"); // use the previously saved session
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);

// Emulate file.
$serialize_args = json_encode($user_data);
    $putData = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
    fwrite($putData, $serialize_args);
    fseek($putData, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $putData);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, drupal_strlen($serialize_args));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// Check if login was successful
$ret;
if ($http_code == 200) {
  // Convert json response as array
  $ret = json_decode($response);
}
else {
  // Get error msg
  $http_message = curl_error($curl);
  die($http_message);
}

print_r($ret);

curl_close($curl);

}



?>
```

What am I missing here?
Nothing happens to my profile.

Any answer is welcomed!

Comment: What did you get from responses. For the $user_data. I think you have to change json_encode($user_data) to http_build_query($user_data)

Comment: "The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized: Missing required argument data"


Hm I have tried that as well without results @StoneVo

Comment: I have a similar problem, 401 error. Did you identify what it was?

Comment: Did any one have get a solution I tried to implement preprocess hook but "user not registered" error message break the execution despite successfully loggedin